# Android Application Wont connect to localhost (Wempserver)

Tags: java, android

My trying an online tutorial for registration and log in and I'v implement everything. But my problem is when I try to press on register after I fill the form and connect to the network it aborts the application showing an error (Unfortunatly learn2crackLogin has stopped)

The name of the application is learn2crachLogin. An I hosted the database files on www in wempserver under the name learn2crack_login_api

I've tried answers to slimier problem but it didn't solve my problem

I'm not sure what screenshots you need so please let me know..

here is my manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
</uses-permission>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/logo1"
    android:label="@string/app_name">

    <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".Login"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
                </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name=".Register">

    </activity>

    <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name=".Registered">

    </activity>

    <activity android:label="Learn2Crack USER PANEL" android:name=".Main">

    </activity>

    <activity android:label="@string/app_name" 
  android:name=".PasswordReset">

    </activity>
    <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name=".ChangePassword">

    </activity>

</application>



</manifest>
```

And here is the UserFunctions.JAVA containing the Localhost link

```
package learn2crack.com.learn2cracklogin.library;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;    
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.content.Context;

public class UserFunctions {

private JSONParser jsonParser;

//URL of the PHP API
private static String loginURL = "http://10.0.2.2/learn2crack_login_api/";
private static String registerURL = "http://10.0.2.2/learn2crack_login_api/";
private static String forpassURL = "http://10.0.2.2/learn2crack_login_api/";
private static String chgpassURL = "http://10.0.2.2/learn2crack_login_api/";

private static String login_tag = "login";
private static String register_tag = "register";
private static String forpass_tag = "forpass";
private static String chgpass_tag = "chgpass";

// constructor
public UserFunctions(){
    jsonParser = new JSONParser();
}

/**
 * Function to Login
 **/

public JSONObject loginUser(String email, String password){
    // Building Parameters
    List params = new ArrayList();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", login_tag));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
    JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(loginURL, params);
    return json;
}

/**
 * Function to change password
 **/

public JSONObject chgPass(String newpas, String email){
    List params = new ArrayList();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", chgpass_tag));

    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("newpas", newpas));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
    JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(chgpassURL, params);
    return json;
}

/**
 * Function to reset the password
 **/

public JSONObject forPass(String forgotpassword){
    List params = new ArrayList();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", forpass_tag));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("forgotpassword", forgotpassword));
    JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(forpassURL, params);
    return json;
}

/**
 * Function to  Register
 **/
public JSONObject registerUser(String fname, String lname, String email,      String uname, String password){
    // Building Parameters
    List params = new ArrayList();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", register_tag));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("fname", fname));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lname", lname));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("uname", uname));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
    JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(registerURL,params);
    return json;
}

/**
 * Function to logout user
 * Resets the temporary data stored in SQLite Database
 * */
public boolean logoutUser(Context context){
    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(context);
    db.resetTables();
    return true;
}

}
```

This is my register.java 
     package learn2crack.com.learn2cracklogin;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import learn2crack.com.learn2cracklogin.library.DatabaseHandler;
import learn2crack.com.learn2cracklogin.library.UserFunctions;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class Register extends Activity {

/**
 *  JSON Response node names.
 **/

private static String KEY_SUCCESS = "success";
private static String KEY_UID = "uid";
private static String KEY_FIRSTNAME = "fname";
private static String KEY_LASTNAME = "lname";
private static String KEY_USERNAME = "uname";
private static String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
private static String KEY_CREATED_AT = "created_at";
private static String KEY_ERROR = "error";

/**
 * Defining layout items.
 **/

EditText inputFirstName;
EditText inputLastName;
EditText inputUsername;
EditText inputEmail;
EditText inputPassword;
Button btnRegister;
TextView registerErrorMsg;

/**
 * Called when the activity is first created.
 */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.register);

    /**
     * Defining all layout items
     **/
    inputFirstName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.fname);
    inputLastName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.lname);
    inputUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.uname);
    inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
    inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pword);
    btnRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.register);
    registerErrorMsg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.register_error);

/**
 * Button which Switches back to the login screen on clicked
 **/

    Button login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bktologin);
    login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Login.class);
            startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            finish();
        }

    });

    /**
     * Register Button click event.
     * A Toast is set to alert when the fields are empty.
     * Another toast is set to alert Username must be 5 characters.
     **/

    btnRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            if (  ( !inputUsername.getText().toString().equals("")) && ( !inputPassword.getText().toString().equals("")) && ( !inputFirstName.getText().toString().equals("")) && ( !inputLastName.getText().toString().equals("")) && ( !inputEmail.getText().toString().equals("")) )
            {
                if ( inputUsername.getText().toString().length() > 4 ){
                    NetAsync(view);

                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Username should be minimum 5 characters", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "One or more fields are empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
}
/**
 * Async Task to check whether internet connection is working
 **/

private class NetCheck extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Boolean>
{
    private ProgressDialog nDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute(){
        super.onPreExecute();
        nDialog = new ProgressDialog(Register.this);
        nDialog.setMessage("Loading..");
        nDialog.setTitle("Checking Network");
        nDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        nDialog.setCancelable(true);
        nDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... args){

/**
 * Gets current device state and checks for working internet connection by     trying Google.
 **/
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnected()) {
            try {
                URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com");
                HttpURLConnection urlc = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlc.setConnectTimeout(3000);
                urlc.connect();
                if (urlc.getResponseCode() == 200) {
                    return true;
                }
            } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return false;

    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean th){

        if(th == true){
            nDialog.dismiss();
            new ProcessRegister().execute();
        }
        else{
            nDialog.dismiss();
            registerErrorMsg.setText("Error in Network Connection");
        }
    }
}

private class ProcessRegister extends AsyncTask<String,Void,JSONObject> {

    /**
     * Defining Process dialog
     **/
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    String email,password,fname,lname,uname;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        inputUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.uname);
        inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pword);
        fname = inputFirstName.getText().toString();
        lname = inputLastName.getText().toString();
        email = inputEmail.getText().toString();
        uname= inputUsername.getText().toString();
        password = inputPassword.getText().toString();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Register.this);
        pDialog.setTitle("Contacting Servers");
        pDialog.setMessage("Registering ...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {

        UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
        JSONObject json = userFunction.registerUser(fname, lname, email, uname, password);

        return json;

    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
        /**
         * Checks for success message.
         **/
        try {
            if (json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) {
                registerErrorMsg.setText("");
                String res = json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS);

                String red = json.getString(KEY_ERROR);

                if(Integer.parseInt(res) == 1){
                    pDialog.setTitle("Getting Data");
                    pDialog.setMessage("Loading Info");

                    registerErrorMsg.setText("Successfully Registered");

                    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
                    JSONObject json_user = json.getJSONObject("user");

                    /**
                     * Removes all the previous data in the SQlite database
                     **/

                    UserFunctions logout = new UserFunctions();
                    logout.logoutUser(getApplicationContext());
                    db.addUser(json_user.getString(KEY_FIRSTNAME),json_user.getString(KEY_LASTNAME),json_user.getString(KEY_EMAIL),json_user.getString(KEY_USERNAME),json_user.getString(KEY_UID),json_user.getString(KEY_CREATED_AT));
                    /**
                     * Stores registered data in SQlite Database
                     * Launch Registered screen
                     **/

                    Intent registered = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Registered.class);

                    /**
                     * Close all views before launching Registered screen
                     **/
                    registered.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    pDialog.dismiss();
                    startActivity(registered);

                    finish();
                }

                else if (Integer.parseInt(red) ==2){
                    pDialog.dismiss();
                    registerErrorMsg.setText("User already exists");
                }
                else if (Integer.parseInt(red) ==3){
                    pDialog.dismiss();
                    registerErrorMsg.setText("Invalid Email id");
                }

            }

            else{
                pDialog.dismiss();

                registerErrorMsg.setText("Error occured in registration");
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    }}
public void NetAsync(View view){
    new NetCheck().execute();
}}
```

logcat

```
04-09 14:42:05.992 3951-3971/learn2crack.com.learn2cracklogin E/Surface:         getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xabd2ef80
04-09 14:42:07.289 3951-3971/learn2crack.com.learn2cracklogin W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
04-09 14:42:07.289 3951-3971/learn2crack.com.learn2cracklogin W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xabe8a180, error=EGL_SUCCESS
04-09 14:42:09.207 3951-3971/learn2crack.com.learn2cracklogin E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xabd2eb90
04-09 14:42:25.120 3951-3974/learn2crack.com.learn2cracklogin E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
                                                                                Process: learn2crack.com.learn2cracklogin, PID: 3951
                                                                            java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
                                                                                at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:309)
                                                                                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
                                                                                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
                                                                                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
                                                                                at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
                                                                                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
                                                                                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
                                                                                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
                                                                             Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: ConnectivityService: Neither user 10064 nor current process has android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE.
                                                                                at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1599)
                                                                                at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1552)
                                                                                at android.net.IConnectivityManager$Stub$Proxy.getActiveNetworkInfo(IConnectivityManager.java:974)
                                                                                at android.net.ConnectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.java:646)
                                                                                at learn2crack.com.learn2cracklogin.Register$NetCheck.doInBackground(Register.java:144)
                                                                                at learn2crack.com.learn2cracklogin.Register$NetCheck.doInBackground(Register.java:122)
                                                                                at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
                                                                                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                                                at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234) 
                                                                                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113) 
                                                                                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588) 
                                                                                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 
04-09 14:42:25.250 3951-3971/learn2crack.com.learn2cracklogin W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
04-09 14:42:25.250 3951-3971/learn2crack.com.learn2cracklogin W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xabe8ae20, error=EGL_SUCCESS
04-09 14:42:27.586 3951-3951/learn2crack.com.learn2cracklogin I/Choreographer: Skipped 138 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-09 14:42:28.139 3951-3971/learn2crack.com.learn2cracklogin E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xabd30d40
04-09 14:42:28.148 3951-3971/learn2crack.com.learn2cracklogin D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllStagingAnimators on 0xa33f5c00 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0xa35b1640
04-09 14:42:28.224 3951-3971/learn2crack.com.learn2cracklogin E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xabd322b0
04-09 14:42:28.989 3951-3951/learn2crack.com.learn2cracklogin E/Surface: queueBuffer: error queuing buffer to SurfaceTexture, -19
04-09 14:42:28.989 3951-3951/learn2crack.com.learn2cracklogin E/Surface: queueBuffer (handle=0xabd30a30) failed (No such device)
04-09 14:42:29.002 3951-3951/learn2crack.com.learn2cracklogin E/ViewRootImpl: Could not unlock surface
                                                                          java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
                                                                              at android.view.Surface.nativeUnlockCanvasAndPost(Native Method)
                                                                              at android.view.Surface.unlockSwCanvasAndPost(Surface.java:301)
                                                                              at android.view.Surface.unlockCanvasAndPost(Surface.java:282)
                                                                              at android.view.ViewRootImpl.drawSoftware(ViewRootImpl.java:2739)
                                                                              at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2642)
                                                                              at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2434)
                                                                              at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2067)
                                                                              at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1107)
                                                                              at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6013)
                                                                              at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
                                                                              at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
                                                                              at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:606)
                                                                              at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844)
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
04-09 14:42:29.008 3951-3951/learn2crack.com.learn2cracklogin I/Choreographer: Skipped 46 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-09 14:43:00.264 3951-3957/learn2crack.com.learn2cracklogin W/art: Suspending all threads took: 13.774ms
04-09 14:44:06.189 3951-3957/learn2crack.com.learn2cracklogin W/art: Suspending all threads took: 16.496ms
04-09 14:47:25.240 3951-3974/learn2crack.com.learn2cracklogin I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 3951 SIG: 9
```

Please please help me

Comment: Which error does it give? Post your logcat output

Comment: @Dr.Pelocho Sorry for that, I just did

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: ConnectivityService: Neither user 10064 nor current process has android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE` Now please explain which part of this nice error message you aren't understanding.

Comment: `ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE` - you fogot this permission.

Comment: the part where I already added <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE> to my manifest. ... isn't it enough ?

Answer (score 0):

I can see more than one error in your code.

1. Replace this

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET">
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
 </uses-permission>`

with

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

2. Replace List with `List<NameValuePair>`
3. Add "?" to your tags like "login?", "register?", ..

Comment: Thank you very much ! When I replace the the List statement the android studio cross the <NameValuePair>.

Comment: I implemnted the other changes and now it tellsme that it is connecting to the server.. then aborts.

Comment: This is apears in the logcat : java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String org.json.JSONObject.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Comment: It seems you didnt understand how to use HTTPURLConnection. You are sending request to google.com in your code and waiting for a response for login :) I reccommend dont waste your time by waiting for a response from google instead take a look at this link for a very simple login application which uses Volley library which is very easy to understand and effective. https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-studio-volley-tutorial-to-create-a-login-application/

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you